# issue with wpf datagrid cell style when scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I created a new DataGridCell style for my wpf datagrid (Red Border brush). When I scroll down vertically the selected cells disappear which is ok. When I scroll up I see the selected cells but few of them missing their style and it appear in wrong cells.

It look like the data grid remember the selected cells but "forget" their style.

Any idea?

haim

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without any more details I can only guess that artifacts you're experiencing are a result of reusing of virtualized cells. You can test this by disabling column and row virtualization:

```
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" ...
```

Also, if this doesn't help did you by any chance override the `Equals` method of your data items? ItemsControls occasionally glitch when they display several equal items.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. 
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" ... 
did the  job for me and for now it’s an OK solution for me because my DataGrid is not so big (about 40 row maximum).
I am going over the code of the WPFToolkit in order to find out how they sync the selection style while recycling/virtualizing in order for my grid to support virtualization.

HAVE A GOOD ONE.

H :-)