# Unexpected behavior of AlternativeRow BackColor in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

I'm styling my `DataGrid` using an style provided by Microsoft at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not changing this style except a single line as following that enables alternative row back color.

```
<!--Style and template for the DataGrid.-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
 ... and the rest of the style
```

I realized a very strange behavior of this style. When you scroll up/down the data grid for few times and then you see that alternative row back color is mixed! such as following image:

[image: mixed alternative back color]

I expect a sequence of light-colored + dark-colored rows which is true before scrolling; but after scrolling everything is randomly mixed-up. Before applying this style I was explicitly setting alternative row color at `DataGrid` definition like following which I never experienced such behavior.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsSource}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF58C9FD" RowBackground="#00000000"/>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion where should I be looking for the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel mentioned that this behavior is a known issue that raises when you try to create a brand-new style for data grid (or in general any item collection).

I tried creating an style based on default style as suggested by Gabriel like following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="OrangeRed"/>
 </Style>
```

I tried overriding all properties I need via this style, and it works fine. Maybe there is a trick/tweak missing in styles provided by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is duplicated in most of styles found on net) that fixes this issue. We still appreciate if anyone updates us.

Meanwhile, I suggest to override default styles by your customization and avoid any brand-new style.

Answer (score 1):

That's a known virtualization problem on WPF DataGrid.

[Here is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749925/4905310), but be aware that it can cause serious performance problems if your dealing with large amounts of data on that DataGrid.

There is a good explanation on the mechanics behind this behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231061/4905310).

Comment: Yeah, actually I have check this option, but the performance penalty is quite serious and unacceptable in my situation. However, as I mentioned, this problem raises **only** when using styling, otherwise setting properties directly in the datagrid definition would not trigger such problems.

Comment: By any chance you use some implicit Style for DataGrid on your project? Because if you do, try and add BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}} on that Style, so that it does not override any settings you made that might have made it work without your custom Style.

Comment: When using Microsoft style or when I define properties explicitly in datagrid definition ?

Comment: I got you're point, but unfortunately when it works fine there is no style :) just explicit property assignment.